# What is the difference between 'the elders' and 'The Empyrean'?

Tags: empyrean-series, fourth-wing, iron-flame

In the Empyrean Series (*Fourth Wing* and *Iron Flame*), there is reference made to a group of leaders within

> dragonkind

who are are essentially the 'leadership' of the group and also responsible for the decisions and culture of the group.

There is also mention of the 'elders' of

> dragonkind,

with whom Andarna

> spends a lot of time with, learning.

**What is the difference between the 'elders' and the 'Empyrean'?**